# Design Bug: Tag alert CSS

Tags: bug, design

The new tag alerts (Thanks ABBY!!!!) need to be properly styled for this site:

[image]

Posted merely for documentation... not complaining at all! Love the new alerts, They'll really help I think.

Comment: Yes please! That yellow really doesn't match our site's style.

Comment: It has the advantage though that it makes these alerts more difficult to miss.

Answer (score 3):

The brown alert box looks OK to me — it's *supposed* to be somewhat jarring.

That said, the link colors inside the box look pretty awful: the links are dark, while the body text is white.  Here's my humble suggestion for improving it:

```css
.message.message-warning a, .message.message-warning a:visited {
    color: #FFEDA4;
}
```

> [image: Screenshot]

I'm still not *quite* 100% happy with the contrast, but at least it's IMO a clear improvement over what we've got now.  (It also pretty closely matches the styling for the red error and blue info messages, which have pink and light blue links respectively.)